# Life after Death

Tags: day-of-judgement, grave, barzakh, surat-al-qiyamah

Salaam ,

From my understanding in your grave after you die, the angels ask you the three questions. If you pass , your grave is widened and your waiting period till day of judgement is peaceful and filled with royalty. Does this mean this person will go to heaven or they have to go through more tests on the day of judgement.

Answer (score 0):

No, no one goes to heaven until Allah orders that that person goes to heaven. So that happens in the day of judgement, not before.

What you said is true, but the person who passes the 3 questions will, like all the dead people, be in a barzakh (half conscious, half-living). But the feeling of the barzakh will depend on what the slave of Allah has been doing in his life on Earth. So his barzakh will be very very peaceful, nice, pleasing to the soul. And in the day of judgement, he will inchaa Allah go to heaven easily for the good that he has done and for the rahma of Allah.